# Access tags/variables in email notifications

Tags: email

I am looking at Design -> Message Pages -> Email Notifications templates.

It seems to me that the variables available in the templates are very limited.

Is there a way to introduce more variables or even tags in the template?

I wanted to use a custom field in a channel to be the sender name instead of `{sender_name}`. Ditto for `{receiver_name}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE System templates are extremely poor and basic. Your best bet is a third-party add-on:

[Libraree](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/libraree)

[Custom System Messages](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages) (I'm pretty sure allows you to customise the email templates)

Also consider [MX Notify Control](http://www.eec.ms/add-ons/mx-notify-control)

Comment: Is there a way to do this in EE3? Is there a native way to do this in EE4/5 or would you need add-ons again?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[sender_name]` and/or `[receiver_name]`.

Comment: How is this different from {sender_name} amd {receiver_name}?

Comment: The tags. You need to use [brackets] instead of {braces}.

Comment: Well, according to the page, the variables are indeed using curly braces. In any case, I do not need those variables. I just want to know if I can use global variables or tags in the templates.

Answer (score 0):

I would checkout Postmaster. https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster

It's by far the most advanced and capable notification add-on for EE with API's to do just about anything. It supports 7 different email services, and allows you to take control over system emails and so much more.

Currently, you can't edit these templates within Postmaster, but it does with any add-on hook (especially with some knowledge of PHP), so it's possible to make any variable (from any hook) available within a template. There are number of hooks included out of the box.

To customize the templates it's really just a matter of override the exp_specialty_templates records with your own content.